# Can't create a Collection of Inherited Classes

Tags: vb.net, class, inheritance, collections

Maybe I just don't know what to search for, but I'm going a little bonkers here trying to figure out how to create a collection of inherited classes. The base class, I will never use.

Basically, I have 3 components:

1. A base class call ImageFormat
2. Child classes of ImageForm
3. Code in Sub Main() to loop create a
   collection and loop through it.

So it does it, #3. The problem is that it always gets the last item added to the collection and uses it's values only.

Here's my Base Class:

```
Public MustInherit Class ImageFormat
    Protected Shared _extentions As String()
    Protected Shared _targettype As String
    Protected Shared _name As String

    Public ReadOnly Property Extentions As String()
        Get
            Return _extentions
        End Get
    End Property
    Public ReadOnly Property TargetType As String
        Get
            Return _targettype
        End Get
    End Property
    Public ReadOnly Property Name As String
        Get
            Return _name
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

And here are the child classes:

```
Class WindowsEnhancedMetafile
    Inherits ImageFormat
    Sub New()
        _extentions = {"EMF"}
        _targettype = "jpg"
        _name = "Windows Enhanced Metafile"
    End Sub
End Class
Class WindowsBitmap
    Inherits ImageFormat
    Sub New()
        _extentions = {"BMP", "DIB", "RLE", "BMZ"}
        _targettype = "jpg"
        _name = "Windows Bitmap"
    End Sub
End Class
Class WindowsMetafile
    Inherits ImageFormat
    Sub New()
        _extentions = {"WMF"}
        _targettype = "jpg"
        _name = "Windows Metafile"
    End Sub
End Class
```

(don't know if these child classes need to different, like just instantied from ImageFormat type or Singleton patterns - would appreciate anything thoughts you have on this)

Then, my routine is:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim imgFormats As New List(Of ImageFormat)
    imgFormats.Add(New WindowsBitmap)
    imgFormats.Add(New WindowsMetafile)
    imgFormats.Add(New WindowsEnhancedMetafile)
    Dim name As String = String.Empty
    For Each imgFormat In imgFormats
        name = imgFormat.Name
        Console.WriteLine(name)
    Next
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

This returns *Windows Enhanced Metafile* three times at the Console. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The three properties:

```
Protected Shared _extentions As String()
Protected Shared _targettype As String
Protected Shared _name As String
```

Are marked as Shared - they belong to the class not the object.

Each time you assign a new value to _name it overrides the old value, thus why you get the same name printed each time.

It should be:

```
Protected _extentions As String()
Protected _targettype As String
Protected _name As String
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, your `_name` et al are `Shared`, which means they are class-level variables. When you're adding `WindowsEnhancedMetafile`, it happens to overwrite these fields with WMF-specific information. If you changed your code to:

```
imgFormats.Add(New WindowsMetafile)
imgFormats.Add(New WindowsEnhancedMetafile)
imgFormats.Add(New WindowsBitmap)
```

you would've had "Windows Bitmap" printed three times.

All you have to do is to change your field declarations to

```
Protected _extentions As  String()
Protected _targettype As String
Protected _name As String
```

Comment: excellent, thank you anton. great explanation. michael got in first, but +1 for you as well.